# Watir Webdriver installation issues

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Error installing Watir webdriver.

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i386-mingw32]
```

I set the SET HTTP_PROXY and then tried as below:

```
 C:\>gem install watir-webdriver
"ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'watir-webdriver' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https:// rubygems . org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0   state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https:// s3 . amazonaws.com / production.s3.rubygems.org / latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError) can't modify frozen object"
```

I then tried...

```
C:\>gem install watir-webdriver  --source http: // rubygems .org
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError) can't modify frozen object
```

Not able to install watir webdriver. Please let me know if there are any additional steps that I need to follow. Thank you!

Comment: why are you using ruby  1.8.7 version. you can also use latest one?

Comment: we have our existing scripts and there are various gems that have dependencies...

Comment: you can try this gem install watir-webdriver --system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a new rubygems update to resolve this problem.
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/671

Updating the gems *manually* to the latest version resolved the problem.

visit -> http://rubygems.org/pages/download

Thought this would be beneficial to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.It might help you.

```
gem update --system
gem install watir-webdriver --system
```

Comment: C:\>gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.

Comment: C:\>gem install watir-webdriver --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --system

Comment: did you install DevKit ?

Comment: if you want to open browser only then you should try it using require "watir" instead of require "watir-webdriver"  and then ie=Watir::Browser.new